# Как сделать push большого файла более 100 мб

Tags: ios, git, github

Нужно залить комит на репозиторий а у меня googlemaps.framework весит 119 мб и он не хочет его заливать. Есть какие то быстрые решения проблемы?

Comment: Вы используете CocoaPods, [как здесь](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)?

Comment: я для ios не пишу, мне просто интересно - а зачем заливать сторонний фреймворк? А если еще и базу с веб-сервером и прочими приблудами целиком залить? Почему бы только свой код не хранить? Например, как [здесь](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-ios) (тот же ios + googlemaps)

Comment: Ёкрн бабай...Не лазивайте бинарники в git, не надо так.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а почему бы и нет? Файлов так 99 по 99 МБ - у вас до сих пор интернет через модем что ли? ))))

Comment: @BOPOH если вы зальёте изменённый файл, то размер увеличится вдвое, так как git хранит все версии.

Comment: Возможно человек прочитал [официальную документацию CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control) - в ней они прямо таки рекомендуют пихать всю папку Pods в репозиторий, вопреки здравому смыслу :)

Comment: @Suvitruf, мне надо было больше смайликов сделать или написать 9999 файлов по 99МБ, чтобы было видно, что это шутка?

Comment: @BOPOH комментарий для тех был, кто не понял шутки и последует вашему совету.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov YIKES! Мне казалось, Ruby-community уже набрало граблей с Bundler'ом, чтобы так не делать, а CocoaPods не просто занимается тем же, а написан на том же языке! Обалдеть. Адъ какой-то.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

### Да. Не заливать его вообще и убрать из коммитов.

Не потому, что это вызывает такие проблемы (хотя и это тоже), а потому, что **он не является частью вашего проекта**, он является **зависимостью**, которую можно загрузить из специальных мест уже после клонирования репозитория вашего проекта.

По-хорошему, [***такими вещами занимается CocoaPods***](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start), менеджер зависимостей. Его идея проста — вы храните в корне репозитория файлик (с названием `Podfile`), в котором несложным DSL описано, от каких библиотек ваш проект зависит. Только непосредственно зависит, зависимости зависимостей он разберёт самостоятельно.

Любой, кто склонировал репозиторий, перед началом работы делает `pod install` в папке с проектом, тем самым загружая и устанавливая в нужные места нужные библиотеки.

Всё, победа.

#### Дополнение:

[Официальная документация](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control) предлагает заливать эти библиотеки в репозиторий. С этим можно жить, пока:

- библиотеки небольшие
- используется собственный сервер контроля версий (где нет боязни наткнуться на плотные ограничения сервиса)

У вас оба пункта не выполняются: вы используете Github и библиотеки у вас крупные. А остальные плюсы держания библиотек в репозитории в документации немножко бессмысленные:

- There is no need to run `pod install`, and no Internet connection is necessary.

  - Один запуск `pod install` и можно уходить в глубокий оффлайн, пока вам не потребуются новые версии библиотек. Но откуда вы их загрузите без интернета?
- The Pod artifacts (code/libraries) are always available, even if the source of a Pod (e.g. GitHub) were to go down.

  - Если опасаетесь, что автор уберёт библиотеку, форкните. Если опасаетесь, что гитхаб ляжет, держите форк на локальной машине и прочитайте [вот это](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html#from-a-podspec-in-the-root-of-a-library-repo).
- The Pod artifacts are guaranteed to be identical to those in the original installation after cloning the repo.

  - Этим уже занимается `Podfile.lock`.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите этот файл из репозитория. Только так. GitHub [не позволяет делать Push коммитов с файлами размером больше 100 мегабайт](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/).

Судя по размерам, это скомпилированый файл библиотеки какой-то внешней зависимости, вероятней всего из CocoaPods. Зависимости не должны присутствовать в репозитории. Вам стоит добавить папку `Pods` в `.gitignore`.